# Como utilizar o Destructuring declarations em kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

```
fun main() {
    val data1 = "27/10/1997"
    val data2 = "23/03/2003"
    val data3 = "13/09/2021"
    val data4 = "01/01/2001"

    imprimirData(data1)
    imprimirData(data2)
    imprimirData(data3)
    imprimirData(data4)
}

fun imprimirData(data: String) {
    val (dia, mes, ano) = data.split("/")
    val mesPorExtenso = when (mes.toInt()) {
        1 -> "Janeiro"
        3 -> "Março"
        9 -> "Setembro"
        10 -> "Outubro"
        else -> "Mês Inválido!"
    }

    
    println("$dia de $mesPorExtenso de $ano")
}
```

[Esse é um exemplo da saída esperada para cada data, porém não consigo imprimir cada data em seu teste especifico, todas as datas estão saindo em um único teste, como posso resolver ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ocK6.png)